# Image not displayed when passed into a JSP from Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

This is my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<% String name = (String)request.getAttribute("name1"); %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%=name%>
<img src=<%=name%>></img>

</body>
</html>
```

When I come to the jsp page by writing the following code in my servlet:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

I see that the path of the image is correctly displayed for

```
<%=name>
```

in the body portion, but the following < img > doesn't get executed and the image is not shown even though it exists in the displayed path.

Comment: add the rendered html code please.

Comment: oh, the rendered html code shown src="" empty string :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a problem with the `<` and `>` inside of a HTML tag. Did you try [JSP El](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html)?

```html
<img src="${name}"/>
```

Comment: if I try this, a black box appears... some improvement :-) but not the image yet.

Comment: Then look at the rendered HTML code and copy the URL in of the `src` attribute to your browser's address bar. Do you see the same?

Comment: Oh no,, the src="" attribute shows empty string in the page source! But I see <body> <%=name%> printing the name fine.

Comment: if I try "<%=name%>", I get this in the src attribute:                          D:\Deepa.jpg. Though the file exists, it doesn't show up!

Comment: you need to provide a path, that is an actual URL. Normally the files you are serving through a Java web application are somewhere in your project's webapp/ directory.

Comment: If I try just what you suggested, src is still blank!

Answer (score 1):

`<img src=<%=name%>>` missing the quotes `<img src="<%=name%>">`

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some path issue. Try this.

```
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/<%=name%>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the scriptlet element in double quote("").

```html
<img src="<%=name%>"></img>
```